# How can I translate "I have improved"?

Tags: traduction, choix-de-mot, usage, verbes

**QUESTION 1. "I have improved"**

How can I translate into French "I have improved"?

Google Translate gives me "Je me suis amélioré" using "to be" instead of "to have."
Is that correct as translation?

**QUESTION2. "I have not only improved my skills"**

How can I translate into French "I have not only improved my skills.."

Google Translate gives me: "Je ne suis pas seulement amélioré mes compétences"
using again "to be" instead of "to have."
It doesn't sound right to me.
Is that translation correct?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first sentence needs more context. Does the sentence end there? Or are you trying to say "I have improved..." followed by a noun?

If all you're saying is, "I have improved." in the sense, "I have gotten better," then

> "Je **me suis** amélioré(e)."

is perfectly fine.

The verb "s'améliorer" is **reflexive**, which is why Google Translate used "être" for the auxiliary in the past tense.

---

Otherwise, "to improve (something)," or "**améliorer** (quelque chose)" in French, follows **transitive** verb rules in French, which means you would use "avoir" as your auxiliary in the past tense.

So if you just use "avoir" in place of "être" in the second sentence that Google Translate provided, it would work fine:

> "Je **n'ai pas** seulement amélioré mes compétences..."

If you're looking for sites that give you more examples and have their own forums, I use [WordReference](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/improve).

Comment: Thank you. Yes the first phrase end just there. While the first sentence seemed right to me, since also in italian we use reflexive verb in that way (using to be), the second sentence seemed not right in Google Translate. Now is clear. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Q1: *Je me suis amélioré* is technically correct but I would prefer *J'ai fait des progrès* which is more idiomatic.

Q2: I would say *Je n'ai pas amélioré que mes compétences* although *compétences* might not be the best translation. We do not know what else has been improved. Perhaps *Je n'ai pas fait de progrès qu'en technique* would better translate that sentence.

Comment: _J'ai fait beaucoup de progrès_, ça marche aussi ?

Comment: @user26328 Oui, pour *I improved a lot*

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1**

The Google translation is correct. Keep in mind that you can't translate word for word a language.
so "I have improved in math" would be "Je me suis amélioré en maths"

**Question 2**

Google isn't correct, you're right. The correct translation is "Je n'ai pas que amélioré mes compétences".

Hope I helped! Use this website for translating (I'm french, but I use this for German): http://www.systranet.com/translate

Comment: *Pas que amélioré* should be *pas qu'amélioré*.

Comment: @jiliagre both work

Comment: The former is indeed sometimes heard but is breaking the elision rules.